# sqlalchemy with_hint not working

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to produce a query with the Postgresql `ONLY` keyword from SQLAlchemy expressions:

**Example 1**: Defining the table name with the `text()` expression doesn't work (except if I put the string "ONLY" as part of the text):

```
tbl = text('schema.table')  # work with text('ONLY schema.table')
query = select([func.count()]).select_from(tbl).with_hint(tbl,
                                                          'ONLY',
                                                          'postgresql')
print query.compile(bind=engine)
```

Prints:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_1
FROM schema.table
```

---

**Example 2**: However if I use the lightweight [`table`](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_1_0/core/selectable.html?highlight=table#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.table) expression it does:

```
tbl = table('schema.table')
query = select([func.count()]).select_from(tbl).with_hint(tbl,
                                                          'ONLY',
                                                          'postgresql')
print query.compile(bind=engine)
```

Prints:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_1 
FROM ONLY "schema.table"
```

but it's no OK, because of the double quotes around the name

---

Now, bare in mind that I receive a list of schema qualified table names and I want to avoid creating `Table` and `MetaData` objects.

So, to make my questions clear:

**Example 1**: How to make the `ONLY` keyword appear?

**Example 2**: How to specify the schema properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of [v1.3.18](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_13.html#change-bec095ab09a7d9c5c1c4d80e0bfb63b1), [table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html?highlight=table#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.table) accepts a `schema` argument.

```
>>> tbl = sa.table('table', schema='schema')
>>> query = sa.select(sa.func.count()).select_from(tbl).with_hint(tbl, 'ONLY', 'postgresql')
>>> print(query.compile(engine))
SELECT count(*) AS count_1 
FROM ONLY schema."table"
```